# Start new activity in PagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-viewpager

I'm using [ViewPagerExtensions](https://github.com/astuetz/ViewPagerExtensions). I would like to start a new activity in each tab in the Pager Adapter class.

Right now this is the default code:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    RelativeLayout v = new RelativeLayout(mContext);

    TextView t = new TextView(mContext);
    t.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    t.setText(mData[position]);
    t.setTextSize(30);
    t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    v.addView(t);

    ((ViewPager) container).addView(v, 0);

    return v;

}
```

I would like to do something as it is done for the android tabs:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, NewActivity.class);

}
```

This throws the error: `The method setClass(Context, Class<?>) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (PagerAdapter, Class<NewActivity>)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I afraid you can't able to do.

If you want diffrent layout for each page:

```
View parent_view = null;

    if (position == 0) {
        parent_view = getViewForPageOne();

    } else if (position == 1) {
        parent_view = getViewForPageTwo();

    .........

    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(parent_view, 0);
    return parent_view;

}
```

and

```
private View getViewForPageOne(){
    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_page_one, null);
     TextView whatText =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.idOfTextView);
     whatText.setText("Page One");
     ....
     ....

     return v;
}
```

I think you can not display new activity in each tab with ViewPagerExtensions

**Update**

If you want to start new activity. You can use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So the calculator class would have to be re-coded in this format?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to inflate the layout of those activities instead of?

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_layout, null);

    /** Find your layout Views. */
    TextView text= (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.any_id);

    // Set some values to your Views.

    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(layout);

    return layout;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I want to display a calendar in one of the tabs. I have a class from here:http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar How would I do that?

Comment: @input, have you ever tried to inflate the simple_calendar_view xml layout file?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this. really appreciate your help if you could tell me how to that?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/) example related with fragments and tabs (I think you pretend to do something like that).

Comment: Can you just clear this one question for me - Do i have to write the whole code from Calendar.java again in the PagerAdapter? Or am I missing something on how to do this?